# How to convert Object of Object into single Object in React

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I am fetching strapi relational data.That data is in complex structure. I would like to change that  as single array of Object file.

This is 1st index response data from strapi.

[image: This is 1st index response data from strapi.].

I want change the entire data as single array of object

[image: I want change the entire data as single array of object]

I am expecting it as single array of object file.

```
{
    id: '',
    item_name: '',
    item_type: '',
    is_returnable:'',
    item_detail: {
        id: '',
        ean: '',
        isbn: '',
        sku: '',
        upc:''
     },
    item_dimension:{
            id: '',
            height: '',
            weight:'',
            new_unit: { id: '', unit_name: '', unit_value: ''\ },
          },
      ... 
   
  }
```

Comment: Known your question is unclear, maybe you would want this kind of solution? [npm: flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat)

Comment: what is the formation of data that you are receiving?

Comment: It's more like Nested objects but as mentioned in the image No.4(index) indicate item table, but item_details table data are in inside of item_detail/data/attributes/. So its bit complicated while take the data, I need to convert it to simple nested object or simple object

Comment: Thanks alot for your replies. I got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply map it

like this :

```
 let mappedData = data.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      ...item.attributes,
      item_detail: item.attributes.item_detail ? {
        ...item.attributes.item_detail.data.attributes,
        id: item.attributes.item_detail.data.id,
      } : {},
      item_dimension: item.attributes.item_dimension ?  {
        ...item.attributes.item_dimension.data.attributes,
        id: item.attributes.item_dimension.data.id,
        new_unit:item.attributes.item_dimension.data.attributes.item_id.data
      } : {},
      is_returnable: item.attributes.is_returnable,
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution bro. It really helped me. Once again thank you bro

Comment: it's my pleasure, if it was what you were looking for please  mark it as the answer and vote up

Comment: you can check if object exist spread that if not set {}, let me update my answer

Comment: updated my answer, is that what you want ?

Comment: Thanks alot 
Ali Sattarzadeh's user avatar
Ali Sattarzadeh . I Solved it

Comment: happy to hear that, if it was what you were looking for please mark it as the answer and vote up